# Sign in with Apple not redirecting back to my website on Google Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have setup Sign in with Apple, it works fine on Safari but not on Chrome.

I get this white page:

[image: white page after signing in with apple]

I'm using [omniauth-apple](https://github.com/nhosoya/omniauth-apple) with this config (same as in the README):

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(
    :apple,
    ENV.fetch("APPLE_CLIENT_ID"),
    "",
    scope: "email name",
    team_id: ENV.fetch("APPLE_TEAM_ID"),
    key_id: ENV.fetch("APPLE_KEY_ID"),
    pem: ENV.fetch("APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY"),
  )
end
```

Any idea why it doesn't work on Chrome?

You can try it live at [urbanparty.fr](https://urbanparty.fr)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of uBlock Origin, I disabled it and now it works